# What is a Bumpy Word™?

Tags: pattern, wordplay, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word has a certain property, I call it a Bumpy Word™.

You can use the examples below to find the property:

| Bumpy™ | Not Bumpy™ |
| --- | --- |
| ARMY | NAVY |
| BUMPING | JERKING |
| CABAL | CONSPIRACY |
| CHASER | PURSUER |
| COALESCE | SOLIDIFY |
| COMPOSITE | DIVERSE |
| CRANK | TURN |
| CRAZY | INSANE |
| EXAMINATION | TEST |
| FERAL | UNCIVILIZED |
| HIGHER | GREATER |
| JUMPING | LEAPING |
| ORATOR | SPEAKER |
| QUALITATIVE | SUBJECTIVE |
| SQUASH | CRUSH |
| THRASH | SPASM |
| TRUSTING | BELIEVING |
| UPWARD | SKYBOUND |
| VAULTING | CAVERNOUS |
| WELDED | FUSED |

Here is a CSV version:

```
Bumpy™,Not Bumpy™
ARMY,NAVY
BUMPING,JERKING
CABAL,CONSPIRACY
CHASER,PURSUER
COALESCE,SOLIDIFY
COMPOSITE,DIVERSE
CRANK,TURN
CRAZY,INSANE
EXAMINATION,TEST
FERAL,UNCIVILIZED
HIGHER,GREATER
JUMPING,LEAPING
ORATOR,SPEAKER
QUALITATIVE,SUBJECTIVE
SQUASH,CRUSH
THRASH,SPASM
TRUSTING,BELIEVING
UPWARD,SKYBOUND
VAULTING,CAVERNOUS
WELDED,FUSED
```

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling Stack Exchange™!

Comment: Related http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/21968/woody-words-tinny-words - Which was (very unfairly) closed.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In a word,

> If a letter occurs (in the alphabet) later than the previous letter in the word, let us call it a "rise", otherwise, it's called a "fall". Note that the first letter of a word is neither of these.

Then a Bumpy word is

> A word in which "rise"s and "fall"s occur alternately.

Example:

> A,R(rise),M(fall),Y(rise) | N,A(fall),V(rise),Y(rise).

Why "Bumpy"?

> For a Bumpy word, imagine plotting the letter-indexes in the order they occur in the word. For example, "BUMPING" would be plotted as follows:
>  [image]
>  Alternation between "rise" and "fall" obviously means that the graph is more "uneven" or "bumpy".

Comment: Should Ankoganit add that alternating "rise" and "fall" is what makes it called bumpy...? The answer looks pretty clear to me.

Comment: This is clearly missing the phrase "simply take the derivative of distance through the alphabet with respect to distance through the word".