# What is a Stair Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series inaugurated by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with his original [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

If a phrase adheres to a certain rule, then I call it a Stair Word™.

Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Stair Words™ | Not Stair Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| PANAMA | AFRICA |
| SOUPY | SOLID |
| WICKER | WACKER |
| INLET | OUTLET |
| WAIF | LADY |
| ENCHANT | IMPRESS |
| BORN | BARN |
| SIGN | SINE |
| QUALM | QUILT |
| BICKER | ARGUE |
| FARADAY | EINSTEIN |
| CALM | STORMY |
| FOULER | VULGAR |
| BANANA | ORANGE |
| MANAGE | GOVERN |
| BUCKET | PITCHER |

In case you want it in CSV:

```
Stair Words™, Not Stair Words™
PANAMA, AFRICA
SOUPY, SOLID
WICKER, WACKER
INLET, OUTLET
WAIF, LADY
ENCHANT, IMPRESS
BORN, BARN
SIGN, SINE
QUALM, QUILT
BICKER, ARGUE
FARADAY, EINSTEIN
CALM, STORMY
FOULER, VULGAR 
BANANA, ORANGE 
MANAGE, GOVERN
BUCKET, PITCHER
```

The puzzle relies on the series' inbuilt assumption, that each wordcan be tested for whether it is a Stair Word™ or not on its own.

Comment: These look mostly like [Bumpy Words™](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42278), except that a couple of them don't quite fit the pattern.  I wonder if they're related, though...

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain - Already checked. Doesn't fit in here Wicker and Wacker both are Non Bumpy.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A Stair Word™ is a word in which

> successive letter sequences (pairs)
> move in opposite directions on the keyboard.

> For example (using an example keyboard image
> that I had lying around in my Pictures folder):
>
>  [image: example keyboard image]

SOUPY and WICKER, for example, adhere to the rule:

> [image: SOUPY and WICKER]

and SOLID and WACKER, for example, do not:

> [image: SOLID and WACKER]
>
> as L→I→D is two consecutive moves to the left,
> and A→C→K is two consecutive moves to the right. 
> (Arguably, S→O→L is also two consecutive moves to the right,
> but O→L is nearly vertical.)

These are called Stair Words™ because they are suggestive

> of a multi-flight staircase, zig-zagging back and forth:
>
>          [image: multi-flight staircase]
>          <sup>(Image derived from http://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/EP1181423B1/imgf0001.png)</sup>

Comment: Oh man! I walked the stairs but didn't knew where I was walking. +1

Comment: Curses. I even looked at positioning and didn't notice what you saw.  +1 from me as well

Comment: @Rubio - How can you miss it man! C'mmon you got the vexed one right :D

Comment: I know, right?!  Kicking myself down the ... uh.... stairs.

Comment: @Techidiot I couldn't see it either, and I WROTE the vexed one.

Comment: I was (partly) inspired by [What is a Waterfall Word™?](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/44573/19765), which makes me all the more surprised that nobody got this before me.

Comment: I just revisited the words and I am confused as to how BARN is a stair word? And why BORN is not? Its either wrong example or may be this stair logic has some flaw. Can anyone explain? :-/

Comment: @Techidiot: You're misreading the table: BORN is listed as a Stair Word, BARN is listed as Not a Stair Word.

Comment: Ah my first thought was alternating up and down rows on the keyboard, I didn't even consider looking at it horizontally. Good job!